# how to share a Variable between 2 form? global variable in the project

Tags: c#, .net

hi 
i want to share a variable between 2 form.
2 forms is in the one project.
In fact,i want a global variable in the project
how can i do it?

Language: c# .net

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Winforms - Global Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293926/c-sharp-winforms-global-variables)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a static class with static field/property like following:

```
public static class DataContainer
{
    public static Int32 ValueToShare;
}
```

use it in multiple forms like following:

```
    public void Form1_Method()
    {
        DataContainer.ValueToShare = 10;
    }

    public void Form2_Method()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(DataContainer.ValueToShare.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a public [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) property/method/variable.

Comment: where must Definition this variable؟

Comment: You can define this within a class/static class that both forms have access to. Why do you wish to do this?

Comment: i need this for a data base application.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `static class` with `static properties` inside that. That will do it.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward way is to pass the variable to the forms.

It's hard to get into too much detail without knowing what your program does and how the forms are loaded, but I'd have the forms accept an argument in the constructor or something. If the argument is a reference type, both forms would reference the same data.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data in (and get data out), I created a custom UserControl and placed it on the main form. This allowed me to then look-up the UserControl from other forms and manipulate the properties on it.