# How to code in C# for accessing Form 1 checkedBox by Form2 and do some action in Form2

Tags: c#, forms, graph

There are two graph in Form2 and user input the tick on check box 1 in Form1 and press load button.After that program show to enable chart1 or chart2.As an example if user select check box 1 and 2 then show two graph.If user select check box 1 then only show chart1.Please help me by given coding example for this.I attached my interface with this.

[This is a checkbox and load button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/js0MH.png)
[There is a 2 graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LtdW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tamas Szabo and @Danish_k12 wrote you, you need to add a public property in your second form. On Load button click initialize new form2. Then check which checkbox is checked and set the public property you add to the second form accordingly. Then in Load event of the second form, depending on the value of the public property you added show first or second graph.
Here is how you can achieve this:

Form1 - with Form2 as private field

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Form2 form2;

        public Form1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.button_Load.Click += Button_Load_Click;
        }

        private void Button_Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(this.form2 != null)
                this.form2.Dispose();

            this.form2 = new Form2();
            if(this.checkBox1.Checked == true)
            {
                this.form2.IndexOfGraphToShow = 1;
            }

            if(this.checkBox2.Checked == true)
            {
                this.form2.IndexOfGraphToShow = 2;
            }

            if(this.form2.IndexOfGraphToShow == 1 || this.form2.IndexOfGraphToShow == 2)
            {
                this.form2.Show();
                return;
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Select which graph to show", "Choose graph", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            form2.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += Form2_Load;
        }

        public int IndexOfGraphToShow { get; set; }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(this.IndexOfGraphToShow == 1)
            {
                //  TODO: Show first graph
            }
            else if(this.IndexOfGraphToShow == 2)
            {
                //  TODO: Show second graph
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One more thing. Using check boxes in your case is good option only if you can show both graphics at once, as both check boxes could be checked. If you plan to show only one graph consider using option set.

To show each time button was clicked a new form you may store the shown form in a private field. Check if the field is not null on button click. If so dispose the old form and create a new one.

You may consider also using of ShowDialog instead of Show when you show the second form like this:

```
this.form2.ShowDialog();
```

This will create a dialog window and user will not be able to reach the button of the first form as long as second form is open.

Comment: Thank you for your help very much and I will try.

Comment: @wnvko.Thank you for  your code is very much.It works.but Form 2 appearing twice.If you can please give me a solution for that.thank you very much.

Comment: I have updated my answer. It will now show only one form. Consider also using ShowDialog instead of Show to show the form

Comment: @wnko.thank you so much your help.thanks a lot.i will try

Comment: @wnko.It works.thank you so much.but user select both of check box then want to show both of graph.but this if user select both of check boxes this Form 2 show chart 2 only.why is that.can you explain to me.please.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a public variable as Boolean and change the value as per the check box value.

Comment: Thank you.I am newer to this language.please give some code for that.it's great help for me.

Comment: You should add your code in the question. Will guide you from there.

Comment: You can check the below link for sample code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416361/how-to-share-a-variable-between-2-form-global-variable-in-the-project

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution I think would be to create a constructor that takes an two `bool`s as parameters and show the graphs based on those values.

Comment: Thank you.I am newer to this language.Can you give some code for that.It's great help for me

Comment: I don't want to write your code for you. Read up on constructors here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx then create one for your second form.

Comment: Comment here if you get stuck or confused, and I'll try to explain.

Comment: I could not pass check box value(true or false )to form 2.please help

Comment: I couldn't pass form1 check box property(true or false) to form2. please can you help.

Comment: Edit your question with what you wrote, and I'll see what's wrong.