# Passing data from textboxes of one form to datagridview of another form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Form1 NewPage has a datagridview and two buttons AddEntry and EditEntry.Form2 AddEntry has 6 textboxes and ok button.
When i click on AddEntry button,form2 will open.When i enter some data in textboxes and then click ok,it has to add to datagridview of form1.

I've written this code behind AddEntry Button.I'm now able to get data from textboxes.

```
public void AddEntryBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string x = label4.Text;
            using (var obj_Addentry = new AddEntry(x))
            {
                obj_Addentry.ShowDialog();
            }
            this.Close();
        }
```

When i click EditEntry button the row selected data will be appearing in the textboxes to edit.but the problem is,When i click ok button in form2,nothing is done as i've no code for adding the data to datagridview behind ok button of form2.Code for adding the data to datagridview is behind AddEntry button of form1.

What should i write for adding the data to datagrid view behind ok button of form2 instead of writing it behind AddEntry button of form1?

Answer (score 0):

Need to send all the Text box values through id, Then In page 2 fetch the values by using Query String all  use the values in grid view.

Example way:
Page 1:

```
 int ID = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text);
        string url = "Page2.aspx?id=" + ID;
        string fullURL = "window.open('" + url + "', '_blank');";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", fullURL, true);
```

Page 2:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
            lblid.Text = ID.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: OMG @Nani that is about win forms not web.

Answer (score 0):

Save your values globally and access it anywhere.
you create class for that.

refer this  [Global variables class](http://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variable)

and this  [C# - Winforms - Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293926/c-sharp-winforms-global-variables)

Answer (score 0):

1.Write down delegate and event in AddEntry form.
2.on click of ok button in form2 raise event
3.assign event handler in form1 Newpage

e.g.

```
public delegate void EditCompletedEvent(List<string> strEditedValues);
public event EditCompletedEvent EditCompleted;

public void OKBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (this.EditCompleted!= null)
                {
                    EditCompleted(listofEditedvalues);
                }
}

//And in form1 assign event handler

public void AddEntryBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string x = label4.Text;
            using (var obj_Addentry = new AddEntry(x))
            {
              obj_Addentry.EditCompleted += 
                   new Form2.EditCompletedEvent(obj_Addentry_EditCompleted)
              obj_Addentry.ShowDialog();
            }
            this.Close();
        }

obj_Addentry_EditCompleted(List<string> Editedvalues)
{
//Write down logic for assignment
}
```