# Set label as static item or improve object reference

Tags: c#, winforms, reference, static

So I'm trying to check if some files exist when the program is loading. And I'm having trouble with cross referencing different forms:

`An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'OnePlus_One_Toolkit.Main.CMOS_check'`
This applies to all of the checks ran in the code below (from the splash):

```
        private void Splash_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        ProcessStartInfo si = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        si.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        si.CreateNoWindow = true;
        si.UseShellExecute = false;
        si.FileName = "adb.exe";
        si.Arguments = "start-server";
        p = Process.Start(si);
        p.WaitForExit();
        if (!File.Exists("stock.zip"))
        {
            Main.flash_stock.Enabled = false;
            Main.CMOS_check.Text = "Download the zip!";
        }
        if (!File.Exists("OOS.zip"))
        {
            Main.flash_OOS.Enabled = false;
            Main.OOS_check.Text = "Download the zip!";
        }
        if (File.Exists("stock.zip"))
        { Main.CMOS_check.Text = ""; }
        if (File.Exists("OOS.zip"))
        { Main.OOS_check.Text = ""; }
        this.Close();
    }
```

How would I go about fixing this. Or even improve my object reference?
And just some extra info the labels and buttons I want to change are set to internal. And the splash does run after the initialize from the primary main form. And the splash is run as a child.

The Main form calling code is below:

```
public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Splash splash = new Splash();
            splash.ShowDialog();
        }
```

The code should check to see if the files exist, and if they don't change the respective labels in the main form.

Comment: What is `Main` here ?

Comment: Nothing Yet.. I'm still editing and adding things

Comment: What is your reason behind trying to use them as `static` ?

Comment: So I can change the text from the labels that are on the Main form that tell the user if they need to download files.

Comment: You could do that without static as well.

Comment: Could you post an answer as to how please? Anything is appreciated.

Comment: Is this `Splash_Load` some other form than `Main` ? Separate forms ?

Comment: Yep. There seperate forms. Which is why I'm having trouble... I tried doing it via the static methods but I broke the designer in the process...

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring because you are trying to access those controls as if they are `static` controls while they are not. Also. there is no State management available in windows forms application.

See this link : [C# - Winforms - Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293926/c-sharp-winforms-global-variables)

This link is the solution that you might be looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I followed up my static issue and it turns out I needed to remove the `this.x` in the designer and now it works a treat :) thanks for the help. Have an upvote.