# how to store some values into windows service like session in web?

Tags: windows, session, c#-4.0, windows-services

I'm having some values which will updates frequently. i want to store this value as session we are using in web project. for i.e. `var lastRunTime = DateTime.Now`
This variable `lastRunTime` needs to keep persistence up to next time scheduler run.

How to store some values into windows service like session in web?

Comment: 1. in Static variable(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293926/c-sharp-winforms-global-variables)
2. In ApplicationSettings(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application)

Answer (score 1):

1. in Static variable([C# - Winforms - Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293926/c-sharp-winforms-global-variables))
2. In ApplicationSettings([Best practice to save application settings in a Windows Forms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application))

mark as answar if helps