# Save a value in a class and use it for any form

Tags: c#, class

I'm using two forms. In first `Form1` I have a `TextBox` from which I send a value into a class `Class1`. 
Here is my `Form1` Code:

```
Class1 ss = new Class1();
ss.name = textBox1.Text;
```

Here is My Class Code:

```
class Class1
{
    public string name;
}
```

But when I open another Form. Example `Form2` and I'm trying to take the value from `Class1` it returns `null`.

Here is my `Form2` Code:

```
 Class ss = new Class();
 textBox2.Text = ss.name;
```

How can I use `public string name` for any Form I open?

Comment: Probably at your level you should use a static variable.  If you don't know what a static variable is, stop what you're doing and go read up about it.  In fact, you should stop everything you're doing, go get CLR Via C#, read it over the course of a day, and then come back to this.

Comment: Make that class static. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Winforms - Global Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293926/c-sharp-winforms-global-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that it is not the same instance in the 2 forms. In the second you create a new instance with an empty `name` variable

> How can i use public string "name" for any Form i open?

if you only use it as a container to pass data then make the `name` variable `static`. That would mean that it exist only once! but you don't need an instance to access the variable!

```
class Class1
{
    public static string name;
}
```

Then you can pack it in `Form1`

```
Class1.name = textBox1.Text;
```

and unpack it in `Form2`:

```
textBox2.Text = Class.name;
```

But the preferable option would be to pass the variable `Class1 ss` that you feed with the `textBox1.Text` into the `Form2` maybe via the constructor

**Form2**

```
public Form2(Class1 c)
{
     textBox2.Text = c.name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new class which will have a new 'empty / null' name value by default.  You need to either use the same class or make the name static.
Just to make this example work, the easy solution would be static but I don't think in the end that this is what you're going to want.

```
public static string name;
```

Comment: " You need to either use the same class" He is using the same class, just not the same instance

Comment: Ok wise crack... You know exactly what I meant.  Yes, you are correct, the same 'instance'.  It should have been worked creating a new 'instance' ... use the same 'instance'.